# Как перейти в директорию в консоли в Win7

Tags: windows, консоль

Для установления библиотеки требуется перейти в нужную директорию через консоль и мне остаётся только надеяться на Вашу помощь, так-как консоль это для меня что-то фантастическое. В примере написано вот как -

> Переходим в папку проекта
>
> cmd
>
> cd /d e:/localhost/sitename

Что это значит?

Comment: @shatal, открою Вам страшную тайну.Набираете в консоли    help cdчитаете и думаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пуск, в строке поиска набираешь cmd (для vista и выше), выбираешь из найденного cmd.exe (по идее это будет единственный вариант). В появившемся окне пишешь `cd /d e:/localhost/sitename` и нажимаешь enter.

А вообще это вопрос для http://user.hashcode.ru/